# Getting error with converted SQL statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, oracle

I'm trying to execute the below statement on PostgreSQL 12.4. This statement was converted from Oracle 10g to PostgreSQL 12.4 using the online [SQL Lines](http://www.sqlines.com/online) tool.

```
select
        hid,
        pname,
        starting_from,
        ename
    from schema1.pet
    where hid=COALESCE(TO_NUMBER(sys_context('temp1','hid')),0);
```

I'm getting the below error:

```
ERROR:  function sys_context(unknown, unknown) does not exist
LINE 7:  where hid=COALESCE(TO_NUMBER(sys_context('temp1','hid...
```

I'm not sure what's the equivalent of `sys_context` in PostgreSQL.

How can I fix this statement to PostgreSQL?

Comment: You should add a description of what `sys_context` does, then you could also reach those people who are not familiar with Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

The [PostgreSQL `current_setting()` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html) comes closest to the Oracle `sys_context()` function. PostgreSQL does not use the `namespace` parameter, however.